# Pandas ValueError Arrays Must be All Same Length

Tags: python, pandas

Iterates over a big list of .mp3 links to get the metadata tags and save it to an Excel file. Results in this error. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
    #print is_connected();

    # Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Links' : lines ,'Titles' : titles , 'Singers': finalsingers , 'Albums':finalalbums , 'Years' : years})


    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlspath, engine='xlsxwriter')

    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    #df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')


    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp.py", line 87, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Links' : lines ,'Titles' : titles , 'Singers': finalsingers , 'Albums':finalalbums , 'Years' : years})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 266, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 402, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5409, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5457, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Answer (score 153):

you can do this to avoid that error

```
a = {'Links' : lines ,'Titles' : titles , 'Singers': finalsingers , 'Albums':finalalbums , 'Years' : years}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
```

**Explanation:**

This creates the DataFrame as each key (e.g. `'Links'`) was a row and like this the missing values are actually missing columns which is no problem for pandas (only missing rows lead to `ValueError` during creation) After that you transpose the DataFrame (flip the axis) and make the rows to columns, which results the DataFrame you initially wanted.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It adds the index as the first row, and split the rows apparently randomly

Comment: try this answer from a different question, which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052003/4682460

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: I too am curious about how exactly this works. Meanwhile, I'm happy that it does work. Values in `a` shorter than the longest list in `a` get padded with `None`, which is what one would expect in that case.

Comment: @Richard This works as it creates the DataFrame as each key (e.g. 'Links') was a row and like this the missing values are actually missing columns which is no problem for pandas (only missing rows are during creation) and then you transpose the dataframe (flip the axis) and make the rows to columns, which results you the dataframe you initially wanted. Did that help?

Comment: Salute to you Sir! That worked

Answer (score 16):

You can pad the shortest lists with empty elements:

```
def pad_dict_list(dict_list, padel):
    lmax = 0
    for lname in dict_list.keys():
        lmax = max(lmax, len(dict_list[lname]))
    for lname in dict_list.keys():
        ll = len(dict_list[lname])
        if  ll < lmax:
            dict_list[lname] += [padel] * (lmax - ll)
    return dict_list


dict_list = {'Links': [1, 2, 3], 'Titles': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Singers': [1, 2], 'Albums': [1, 2, 3], 'Years': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
dict_list = pad_dict_list(dict_list, 0)
print(dict_list)
```

Output

```
{'Links': [1, 2, 3, 0], 'Titles': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Singers': [1, 2, 0, 0], 'Albums': [1, 2, 3, 0], 'Years': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: what's `padel`?

Comment: @loretoparisi it's something that you would like to use as an element for filling the dictionary values

Answer (score 14):

It's telling you that the arrays (lines, titles, finalsingers, etc...) are not of the same length. You can test this by

```
print(len(lines), len(titles), len(finalsingers)) # Print all of them out here
```

This will show you which data is malformed and then you'll need to do some investigating into what the right way to correct this is.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate variable names caused this problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same error while reading JSON file to the pandas frame. adding linesbool, default False parameter solved the issue.

```
StringData = StringIO(obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
                mydata = pdf.read_json(StringData, lines=True)
```