# ValueError: arrays must all be same length in python using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I'm a newbie in python and using Dataframe from pandas package (python3.6).

I set it up like below code,

```
df = DataFrame({'list1': list1, 'list2': list2, 'list3': list3, 'list4': list4, 'list5': list5, 'list6': list6})
```

and it gives an error like `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

So I checked all the length of arrays, and `list1` & `list2` have 1 more data than other lists. If I want to add 1 data to those other 4 lists(`list3`, `list4`, `list5`, `list6`) by using `pd.resample`, then how should I write code...?

Also, those lists are time series list with 1 minute.

Does anybody have an idea or help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
So I changed as what EdChum said.
and added time list at the front. it is like below.

```
2017-04-01 0:00 895.87  730 12.8    4   19.1    380
2017-04-01 0:01 894.4   730 12.8    4   19.1    380
2017-04-01 0:02 893.08  730 12.8    4   19.3    380
2017-04-01 0:03 890.41  730 12.8    4   19.7    380
2017-04-01 0:04 889.28  730 12.8    4   19.93   380
```

and I typed code like

```
df.resample('1min', how='mean', fill_method='pad')
```

And it gives me this error: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd just construct a `Series` for each list and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) them all:

```
In [38]:
l1 = list('abc')
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
s1 = pd.Series(l1, name='list1')
s2 = pd.Series(l2, name='list2')
df = pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1)
df

Out[38]: 
  list1  list2
0     a      1
1     b      2
2     c      3
3   NaN      4
```

As you can pass a `name` arg for the `Series` ctor it will name each column in the df, plus it will place `NaN` where the column lengths don't match

`resample` refers to when you have a `DatetimeIndex` for which you want to rebase or adjust the length based on some time period which is not what you want here. You want to `reindex` which I think is unnecessary and messy:

```
In [40]:
l1 = list('abc')
l2 = [1,2,3,4]
s1 = pd.Series(l1)
s2 = pd.Series(l2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':s1.reindex(s2.index), 'list2':s2})
df

Out[40]: 
  list1  list2
0     a      1
1     b      2
2     c      3
3   NaN      4
```

Here you'd need to know the longest length and then `reindex` all Series using that index, if you just `concat` it will automatically adjust the lengths and fill missing elements with `NaN`

Answer (score -1):

According to [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), it looks quite difficult to do this with `pd.resample()` : You should calculate a frequence which add only one value to your df, and the function seems really not made for this ^^ (seems to permit easy reshaping, ex : 1 min to 30sec or 1h) ! You'd better try what EdChum did :P