# Python Pandas "All arrays must be of the same length" Problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting an error like this. Thank you in advance for your solutions.

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

```
a = {"Ana Linkler":linkler, "İç Linkler":ic_linkler, "Sorular":sorular}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Comment: Check `len(linkler)`, `len(ic_linkler)`, `len(sorular)`. They should be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this.

```
a = {"Ana Linkler":linkler, "İç Linkler":ic_linkler, "Sorular":sorular}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `df = df.transpose()` at the end, to reach the target `index` and `columns` position.

```
a = {"Ana Linkler":linkler, "İç Linkler":ic_linkler, "Sorular":sorular}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
```

Duplicate question: [Python Pandas ValueError Arrays Must be All Same Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442014/python-pandas-valueerror-arrays-must-be-all-same-length)